# How can I load "jquery-1.4.2" as a module in webpack without modifying its source

Tags: jquery, webpack, webpack-3, webpack-loader

I want to include `jquery-1.4.2` in parallel with `jquery-3.x`. 
I have aliased the paths of both scripts as: `jquery1`/`jquery3`

For jquery-3.x the code below works:

`require("imports-loader?jQuery=jquery3!app/some.jquery.myplugin");`

But If i do the same for jquery1 :

`require("imports-loader?jQuery=jquery1!app/some.jquery.mylegacyplugin");`

I get at runtime: *cannot set property mylegacyplugin of undefined.*

The only solution I found till now is to edit jquery-1.4.2. file and add the following at the end of the function:

`module.exports=jQuery;`

Is there a loader which I can use to avoid editing the source code of jquery?

Comment: Is you jQuery plugin a module or a simple script?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have created a [repo](https://github.com/Legends/exampleWp3_Using_jQueryPlugins) which demonstrates it

Install: `npm i exports-loader -D`.
I see that you have installed the `imports-loader` already.

And I hope you can modify your plugin to add `module.exports`.

**myJQueryPlugin.js**

```
$.fn.greenify = function () {
    debugger;
    this.css("color", "green");
    return this;
}

module.exports = $;
```

**Add the following rule:**

```
 module: {
            rules: [        
                {
                    use: "exports-loader?window['jQuery']",
                    test: /jQuery.1.4.2.js$/
                },
```

**I have added also a resolve.alias for my jQuery plugin:**

```
 resolve: {
      alias: { // shortcuts             
            "myjqPlugin": path.resolve("src/scripts/plugins/app/myJQueryPlugin.js")),
```

**Then in your index.js**

```
// you would probably name this `var` differently:
    var my142jQueryIncludingPlugin = require("imports-loader?$=../../libs/jQuery.1.4.2.js!myjqPlugin");

    my142jQueryIncludingPlugin("*").greenify();
```

**Result**: Everything is green :-)

Comment: Nice! I didn't know that you can also export something that is on window!

Comment: You use the `exports-loader` for scripts that do not export themselves. This old jQuery version does not use any module format to export itself, it just registers itself globally. That's why we need `exports-loader here`